# How do I fix sway waybar not displaying my custom module?

Tags: archlinux, wayland, visualizer

I'm basically a complete beginner when it comes to this stuff.

I'm trying to make a real time custom audio visualizer module that works with waybar. I haven't even touched real time processing yet, right now I just have a script that uses an already existing audio file. I just want to update waybar with this one singular visualization before trying to do real time stuff (and thank god I did). The only thing the module should be doing is basically displaying a bar graph with binned values I have that corresponds to a recording of audio I took.

I'm running Arch Linux, with sway and waybar.

My script is linked [here](https://pastebin.com/DikXVbxY). I also have my module here:

```
"custom/audiovisualizer": {

"format": "{data}",

"return-type": "json",

"exec": "python3 $HOME/scripts/visualizer.py",

"on-click": "pkill -SIGRTMIN+1 waybar",

"signal": 1

},
```

You can see my full config file [here](https://pastebin.com/d391pVxs).

[Here](https://pastebin.com/grUy8r2T) is the output I get when running waybar.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/VPbp0g4c) is the output I get when running waybar with -l trace.

Below I'm going to go through some things I tried that aren't already apparent:

- Yes it has permissions to access the script
- The script doesn't run (I have a print statement that never shows, although I don't know if it ever would)
- I've run waybar in terminal, even with the -l trace mode on, and there was no useful errors other than the one in the title
- I updated waybar 6 hours ago so it's working.
- The configuration is added to the proper class (modules-center)
- The script works fine when I run it myself, with no errors (produces the same output every time). It outputs proper json formatted data (shown below)
  {"data": "\u2588\u2582\u2581\u2581\u2581\u2581"}
- The paths are all good and work
- The script takes a fraction of a second to execute so it's not being killed prematurely.

What can I try next?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this myself, but in my json script-output my first field was named `"text"`, rather than your `"data"`, and in my config I had `"format": "{}"` (I didn't use the label `text` anywhere in the format string. Also, the value in my json output was also surrounded by double-quotes (yours looks to have no quoting). Perhaps you could try some combination of those and see if it helps?